# Button click testing

Tags: java, android, testing, junit

how can I use Junit to test a button click, everything happens in Android studio in java?
I am very bad at Junit testing

```
public class ActivityMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    
    Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMenu.this, Level_Menu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }catch (Exception e){
            }
            
        }
    });}
```

Comment: If you want to test UI stuff, like user interactions and what you see as a result (as opposed to testing the internals the UI interacts with), you need to use a UI testing framework like Espresso: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso

Comment: I need exactly Junit testing